# Lumen - pagination and result editing

Tags: php, rest, pagination, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and trying to make a simple REST API app. I want one of the endpoints to be able to display all records from a "storeItems" table but add a field to each record with its' categories and paginate them.

So at the moment I have the usual

```
$products = DB::table('storeItems as i')
    ->where('i.B2BAvailable', '=', '1')
    ->select('i.title','i.EAN','i.vendor','i.productType','i.ID as productID','i.releaseDate',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN (i.releaseDate > NOW()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS announced'))
    ->orderBy('i.releaseDate', 'desc')
    ->paginate(100);
    return response()->json($products);
```

This gives out the expected result, but if I want to iterate over the results and add a field from a different table...like this:

```
foreach($products as $product) {
        $genres = DB::table('sCategoryConnector as ggc')
        ->join('sCatGenre as gg','gg.ID','=','ggc.ID_sCatGenre')
        ->where('ggc.EAN', '=', DB::raw("'".$product->EAN."'"))
        ->select('gg.tag')
        ->orderBy('gg.ID', 'asc')
        ->get();
        
        if (count($genres) > 0) {
            $i=0;
            foreach($genres as $genre) {
                //$product['genres'][$i] = $genre['tag'];
                $propName = 'genre'.$i;
                $product->genres->$propName = $genre->tag;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But Lumen is outputting: Creating default object from empty value error and marking this line:

```
$product->genres->$propName = $genre->tag;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was rushing a bit...should have replaced assigning genres like this:

```
if (count($genres) > 0) {
            $i=0;
            $product->genres = $genres;
            /*
            foreach($genres as $genre) {
                //$product['genres'][$i] = $genre['tag'];
                $propName = 'genre'.$i;
                $product->genres->$propName = $genre->tag;
                $i++;
            }
            */
        }
```

So the correct way to assign a new property to a StdClass object....
**$product->genres = $genres;**